# How can i package an eclipse-plugin with maven as a folder?

Tags: maven, eclipse-plugin, eclipse-rcp

When i export my eclipse rcp product with eclipse, then it creates my plugin as a folder and everthing works fine. but when i build my product with maven, i can't access images and audio files who are saved in the plugin jar file.
Is it's possible to package a eclipse-plugin as a folder?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Specify:

```
Eclipse-BundleShape: dir
```

in the MANIFEST.MF file for the plug-in to say you want a directory (folder) rather than a jar.

Note: If you use a Feature based build the unpack option in the feature.xml will override this.

See also the [Eclipse help](http://help.eclipse.org/mars/index.jsp?topic=%2Forg.eclipse.platform.doc.isv%2Freference%2Fmisc%2Fbundle_manifest.html)

Eclipse does also provide APIs to allow you to access files in the plug-in jar (mainly `FileLocator`).

Comment: the problem was the unpack optin in my feature.xml.
Thank you very much!